# How to access multiple online cloud storage accounts from a single program?

Tags: software-recommendation, cloud

What would be a good program to use for accessing multiple online file storage accounts like Ubuntu One, Google Drive,etc all from the same program?

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 32 bit on an acer 2x Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU T5450  @ 1.66GHz and 3 gb of RAM.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [InSync](https://www.insynchq.com/) it's not open source, but it's free (for now, at least), and has linux support, obviously.